# проверка на состояние qcheckbox

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside6, pyqt6

Всем привет, очень нужна помощь, так как не могу продвинуться дальше по коду без этой части

Пишу десктопное приложение с использованием PySide6, цель которого хранение аккаунтов и управление ими.

Аккаунты хранятся в отдельном файле accounts.json, далее от туда переносятся в фрейм.

код:

```py
with open(dir_path + '\\accounts.json', 'r') as reading_json:
    readed_data = json.load(reading_json)
    if len(readed_data) < 2:
        widgets.loginfo.insertPlainText('Вы не добавили ни одного аккаунта!\n')
    else:
        for account in readed_data[1::]:
            acccheckbox = QCheckBox(account['login'])
            widgets.cashonly.addWidget(acccheckbox)
            if account['in_list'] == 'yes':
                acccheckbox.setChecked(True)
```

Теперь вопрос, как мне проверить прожат ли чекбокс или нет, если его название мне не известно?

По итогу должно получиться, что при прожатии чекбокса должно меняться значение в accounts.json у 'in_list' с yes на no и наоборот.

loginfo - QTextEdit

cashonly - фрейм на котором располагаются чекбоксы

пример наполнения json файла:

[{"login": "", "password": "", "steam_id": "", "in_list": ""}]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. а также небольшой пример файла `accounts.json`.

Comment: @S.Nick немного не понимаю, как я могу указать такой пример, если нет проблемы в коде, а вопрос как это реализовать...